# Is there a way to write a file to hdfs in a UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to parallelize a Monte Carlo simulation on spark. The input to the simulation is a partition of a data frame and the simulation is currently run in a user defined function. The UDF looks something like this:

```
@udf(returnType=StringType()) 
def run_simulation(str):
    import mcsim
    result = mcsim.run_simulation(str)
    return str
```

The returned result is a list of three rather large data frames which I immediately would like to store as parquet files on hdfs.
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? I'm quite new in the spark context and not sure if using a UDF is the best approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, you're creating a new DataFrame inside your UDF?

Comment: Indeed. The simulation creates resulting tables with three different schemas. I somehow need to store these results in HDFS.

Comment: Are you new to Spark?
Can you please specify exactly what you're striving to?
Input, output, etc. With samples. 
I can help you, I just need more info.

Comment: Indeed, I am new to Spark. We have a table of about 2 million rows in each partition. Each partition is an input to a simulation that is written in C++ and interfaced for example to Python. The simulation results in three different tables with different fortmats which need to be stored in hdfs. I know that this is not a typical use case for Spark. The idea is to use Spark/YARN as a ressource manager to parallelize the simulation runs and ThriftServer to allow to run SQL queries on the resulting large data sets.

Comment: Have you seen https://dask.org/? Pretty good for parallelizing python code